# Bound on the number of distinct subset-sums of a given set

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I am interested in characterizing sets for which the number of different subset-sums is bounded by a polynomial in the size of the set. Formally:

Let $A = \langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m \rangle$ be a multi-set of non-negative integers (repetitions possible). For a subset $A'\subseteq A$, let $s(A')$ denote the sum of elements in $S'$. Then the number of different subset-sums for $A$ is given by $\chi(A) = |\{s(A') : A'\subseteq A\}|$.

In general, $\chi(A)$ can be as large as $2^m$, for $m = |A|$, e.g. when $A = \langle1,2,\dots,2^{m-1}\rangle$. On the other hand, when each $a_i \in [k]$, then the sum of any subset of $A$ lies in $\{0,1,\dots,k\cdot m\}$, and hence $\chi(A) \le k\cdot m+1$, which is polynomial in $m$ if $k = poly(m)$.

I would like to know if there is a general characterization of sets $A$ for which $\chi(A)\le poly(|A|)$? If this is hard, are there other large classes of sets $A$ for which $\chi(A)$ is reasonably small?

Comment: Do you mean $a_i\in [k]?$ $a_i\subseteq [k]$ seems wrong. And you really get $\chi(A)\leq km+1$ in that case, not $\chi(A)=km.$

Comment: thanks, edited.

Comment: But you still have $=km+1,$ which you don't know, you only know $\chi(A)\leq km+1.$

Comment: You can't really talk about individual instances being polynomial in $m,$ because there is always a polynomial. For example, $A=\{1,2,4,8\}$ gives, as you say, $16,$ but $16=4\cdot 4=4m.$ You can only talk about classes of answers over infinitely many $m.$ So, giving a polynomial $p$ you can ask what subsets have $\chi(A)\leq p(|A|),$ but you can't talk about over all polynomials, because there is always a polyn9mial for which any particular $A$ works.

Comment: Of course, which is why I am asking for a class of sets. For e.g. the class of sets where all values are in the interval $[t, t+poly(m)]$ for an arbitrary integer $t$ is such a class.